# Custom infinite vertical stacked carousel

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to create a component that looks like this: [An infinite, vertical, stacked carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT5VI.png)

So far I've been looking through a lot of libraries but none of them satisfy the looks and behaviour completely. The one that was closest to the looks was https://github.com/victor-pavlychko/DeckCollectionViewLayout but as it seems it doesn't have scrolling implemented and I'm not sure how to modify it in order to be working the way it should. Started for some kind of custom solution, but still have no idea what the approach should be: CollectionView with custom layout or maybe something else. Any ideas and advices will be very appreciated ^_^

Comment: You could do this with collection views and a custom flow layout, but that involves a big learning curve. There was an open source 3rd party library called iCarousel years ago that would let you create exactly this look, but I don't think it's being maintained, and probably won't build any more. (It was written in Objective-C)

Comment: I agree on the "big learning curve" part :D .. when looking at how these libraries implemented this behaviour I barely understand something :/ I also looked at iCarousel and tried few stuff but it doesn't seem to have such solution. Now looking at https://github.com/zammitjames/JZStackedView but it doesn't seem to be infinite like it is on the picture :( .. thank you for the advice tho ^_^

Comment: I'm trying to make something similar with SwiftUI at the moment. If I ever finish I can post the source code

Comment: iCarousel can definitely do what you want, assuming it still works with the latest version of Xcode, and you can get the bridging headers to work with Swift.

Comment: The repo comes with a demo app that lets you try the various Carousel modes, and I have a strong memory that the stacked look you are after is one provided by the demo.